# IO monad handling, simplifying bind syntax

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, monads

While writing a small date program as an exercise to practice handling monads in Haskell, I came up with the `localDate` helper function below. I prefer the bind chaining syntax over the do block - please offer any input on whether one syntax conforms more with Haskell standards.

My main question has to do with simplifying `localDate`. Is it possible to pass both getCurrentTimeZone and getCurrentTime to utcToLocalTime without two bind operations?

```
localDate :: IO(Day)
localDate = localDay <$> zoneNow where 
    zoneNow = getCurrentTimeZone >>= \z -> getCurrentTime >>= \t -> return $ utcToLocalTime z t

localDate' :: IO(Day)
localDate' = do
   z <- getCurrentTimeZone
   t <- getCurrentTime
   let zoneNow = utcToLocalTime z t
   return $ localDay zoneNow
```

Comment: You can rewrite this to `utcToLocalTime <$> getCurrentTimeZone <*> getCurrentTime`, and rewrite `localDate` to `localDate = (. localDay) . utcToLocalTime <$> getCurrentTimeZone <*> getCurrentTime`.

Comment: There's also [idiom brackets](https://oleg.fi/gists/posts/2018-07-06-idiom-brackets-via-source-pluging.html)

Comment: and `liftA2`. <empty_space_filler>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `getCurrentTime >>= \t -> return $ utcToLocalTime z t` can be replaced with a functor mapping:

```
getCurrentTimeZone >>= \z -> fmap (utcToLocalTime z) getCurrentTime
```

We can rewrite this further to:

```
utcToLocalTime <$> getCurrentTimeZone <*> getCurrentTime
```

in the `localDate`, you perform another functor mapping, we can thus write this as:

```
localDate :: IO Day
localDate = localDay <$> (utcToLocalTime <$> getCurrentTimeZone <*> getCurrentTime)
```

or we can combine the two functor mappings with:

```
localDate :: IO Day
localDate = (localDay.) . utcToLocalTime <$> getCurrentTimeZone <*> getCurrentTime
```

This thus produces the local day:

```
Prelude Data.Time.Clock Data.Time.LocalTime> (localDay.) . utcToLocalTime <$> getCurrentTimeZone <*> getCurrentTime
2020-04-16
```